# Regex in a bash scipt

Tags: regex, bash

I've got the following text file which contains:

```
 12.3-456, test
 test test test
```

If the line contains xx.x-xxx, then I want to print the line out. (X's are numbers)

I think I have the correct regex and have tested it here:
http://regexr.com/3clu3

I have then used this in a bash script but the line containing the text is not printed out.
What have I messed up?

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if  [[ $line =~ /\d\d.\d-\d\d\d,/g ]]; then
            echo $line
    fi
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` and escape the dot.

Comment: And no slashes or `g`. And escape the `.`. `[[ "$line" =~ [0-9]{2}\.[0-9]-[0-9]{3}, ]]` should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `[0-9]` instead of a `\d` in Bash regex. No regex delimiters are necessary, and the global flag is not necessary either. Also, you can contract it a bit using [limiting quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) (like `{3}` that will match 3 occurrences of the pattern next to it). Besides, a dot matches any character in regex, so you need to escape it if you want to match a literal dot symbol.

Use

```
regex="[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]-[0-9]{3},"
if  [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
...
```

Comment: +1 For putting the regex in a variable. Though "a dot matches any character in Bash" is a bit general as it can mean *globs* for example. I would substitute "Bash" with "regular expressions".

Comment: Yes, I meant the regex module, sorry.

Comment: Thanks - this does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
#regex="/\d\d.\d-\d\d\d,/g"
regex="[0-9\.\-]+\, [A-Za-z]+"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo $line
    if  [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "match"
    fi
done
```

regex is [any of 0-9, '.', '-'] followed by ',' followed by alphachars. This could be refined in a number of ways - e.g. explicit places before/ after '-'.

Testing indicates:

```
$ ./sqltrace2.sh < input.txt 
12.3-456, test
match
123.3-456, test
match
12.3-456,
test test test
test test test
```

Comment: +1 For using *ERE* as `=~` supports. I would remove the curly braces around `regex` ( i.e. `[[ $line =~ $regex ]]` ) as they are not required in this context ( also wrong in this example ) and might confuse begginers who often thinks that they are a substitute for quotes :-)

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein thanks for the feedback - corrected. Brackets as quotes, really? Cheers :-)

Comment: Cool :-) I take back the "( also wrong in this example)" - It's not wrong. I meant to say that if, by mistake, one will use double-quotes around `$regex` it will be wrong. Yes, too many people confuse curly braces around variables with double-quotes - for some reason they expect the same effect. You must admit that they look protective against *word-splitting* :-) Cheers!